# Is there a way to get files modified after and/or before a certain time without using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, wmic

Without using PowerShell or other scripts, and only using built-in Windows command-line programs, I'm trying to find files modified after a certain date and time, but I'm having trouble.  This is the command I'm using:

> wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\path\to\folder\' a
> nd lastmodified>'201905141200'" get name

I've also tried various combinations without quotes around the lastmodified value, however, I keep getting:

> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid query

Is it not possible to query the 'lastmodified' field with WMIC?  Again, I'm trying to do this outside of PowerShell and without scripts -- purely command-line syntax.

Comment: If you're doing it without scripts why are you doing it on the commandline? Why would you not use e.g. the search within the explorer?

Comment: Because I'm accessing the box via ssh.

Comment: Which SSH implementation is the host using? Windows doesn't come with SSH out of the box.

Comment: Also why is PowerShell not an option? It is a built-in Windows command-line.

Comment: @Burgi I didn't set up the box, one of my admins did.  Based on the path of the process, I'd say he installed OpenSSH-Win64.

Comment: @Seth Windows actually comes with SSH now as of Windows 10 1809.  Albeit, this box (windows 7) doesn't come with it built-in, obviously.

Comment: @Seth Also, avoiding Powershell to avoid event logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... the `lastmodified` value being queried has to be in this format:

`YYYYMMDDHHmmSS.NNNNNN-###`

YYYY = Year
MM = Month
DD = Day
HH = Hour
mm = Minute
SS = Second
NN = Nanosecond
### = 3 digit number (I guess '000' would be fine?)

Therefore, the correct command would be something like:

> `wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\path\\to\\folder\\' a
>   nd lastmodified>'20190515074900.000000-000'" get name`